# Python: How to display in a full screen and determine the number of players

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new in python and I would like to ask after I determine the number of players playing how will it pop out to input the player's name. This is the code that I have constructed so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')


#No. of players

player_text=StringVar()
player_choices = ['1','2','3','4']
player_text.set('Players')

def players_playing(*args):
    print( player_text.get() )

player_text.trace('w', players_playing)
Players = tk.Label(root, 
         text="Input the number of Players:",
         fg = "red",
         font = "Times") #Label widget

Players.pack()
Players.grid(row=0, sticky = E)

player = OptionMenu(root, player_text, *player_choices)
player.grid(row=0, column=1)

if player_choices == '0':
    Player1 = tk.Label(root, 
         text="Player1: ",
         fg = "Black",
         font = "Times")
    Player1.grid(row=1, sticky = E)`enter code here`

    entry_1 = Entry(root)
    entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop() #window wont appear if this code doesnt exist
```

Comment: you would like to ask user to input player name via pop-window? If yes, you can create a `top-level` window, which contains `Entry` widget. After user insert a name, you can pass it to your main window.

Comment: How do you do a top-level window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I code a sample program that show you how you can create a pop-up window.

```
import tkinter as tk

def pop_up(root):
    # Create top level window for user to input 
    save_window_toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
    save_window_toplevel.geometry("400x200+100+100")
    # Initiate a save window
    save_window = SaveWindow(master=save_window_toplevel)
    # wait user to input valid filename
    save_window_toplevel.wait_window()


class SaveWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, relief="solid")
        self.top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="none", expand=True)
        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text="Player Name: ")
        self.label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.top_frame, width=20)
        self.username_entry .grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="Save", command=lambda: self.read_username())
        self.save_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
        self.name_valid = False
        self.username = None

    def read_username(self):
        temp_username = self.username_entry.get()
        if temp_username == '':
            print("No valid name")
            return
        else:
            self.name_valid = True
            self.username = temp_username
            self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    pop_up_button = tk.Button(root, text="Pop-Up", width=10, command=lambda : pop_up(root))
    pop_up_button.pack(side='left')
    root.mainloop()
```

So what you can do, you can call the `pop_up` function when you need. There is one more thing that you can improve. You can create the multiple `entry` field based on the number of player number.

I hope it will help

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll be surely trying this code and hopefully, it will help me!